# Order of adding Mimetypes in a web. config file

Tags: xml, html, svg, mime-types

I am trying to having a svg. file display in safari and yeah, i have searched through alternatives and found that i am supposed to both include:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml">
```

in the head section of my html files. I also learnt that i am supposed to configure the web. config file by including this too:

```
<staticContent><mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" /></staticContent>
```

The problem is that upon doing that, the site stops functioning displaying a blank screen with an error. Is it that am not placing the  in the right place as i realised that if i remove it, the pages functions well again? This is how i had organised the order before it the website stopped working.

```
    <system.webServer>
        **<staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="images/svg+xml" />
        <staticContent>**
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="Index.php" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See update if you can not used system.webServer settings.

Answer (score 3):

You should already have a ApplicationHost.config file which contains the <system.webServer>

Per this sample http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver

and expect it to have a few entries like

```
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/gif" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".htm" mimeType="text/html" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpeg" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/jpeg" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/x-javascript" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".txt" mimeType="text/plain" />
```

add

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="images/svg+xml" />
```

there.

I would not try to make a new config file because you would need all the other entries, which I am guessing is what is causing the error message. Nor should there be two staticContent sections.

**Alternative method** 
Using a php wrapper to deliver the svg with correct header type.

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: image/svg+xml");
include("mysvgfile.svg"); 
?>
```